# Pandas - create a new string column based on the values of a datetime column

Tags: python, pandas

The below code creates a new column season that assigns a 'season' depending on the value of the date column.

```
df2.season = None
df2.loc[(df2.date=='2010-02-22 00:00:00'), 'season'] = '2009/2010'
df2.loc[(df2.date=='2011-02-22 00:00:00'), 'season'] = '2010/2011'
df2.loc[(df2.date=='2014-09-19 00:00:00'), 'season'] = '2014/2015'
df2.loc[(df2.date=='2012-02-22 00:00:00'), 'season'] = '2011/2012'
df2.loc[(df2.date=='2013-09-20 00:00:00'), 'season'] = '2013/2014'
df2.loc[(df2.date=='2015-09-10 00:00:00'), 'season'] = '2015/2016'
df2.head()
```

Is there a way of doing this in fewer lines of code with a loop?

I've tried `pd.cut()` but that throws up an error due to the `datetime` values in the date column.

I imagine there's a way of zipping date and season values and then using a loop but I don't know how to go about this. Thanks!

Comment: What is logic here? datetimes to last june and datetimes after last june?

Answer (score 0):

If logic is datetimes before and after last june day use:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

y = df["date"].dt.year
y1 = y.astype(str)
y2 = (y - 1).astype(str)
y3 = (y + 1).astype(str)

df["season"] = np.where(df["date"].dt.month > 6, y1 + '/' + y3, y2 + '/' + y3)
print (df)
        date     season
0 2010-02-22  2009/2011
1 2011-02-22  2010/2012
2 2014-09-19  2014/2015
3 2012-02-22  2011/2013
4 2013-09-20  2013/2014
5 2015-09-10  2015/2016
```

Comment: Thank you! I realise I've been over-complicating things.

Comment: @SatyaD - So `datetimes are before and after last june day` ?